# Spring API application/json is not working when getting text/json content type

Tags: json, spring, api

I'm querying a PhraseApp API to get translations and setting the content type on the headers as appplication/json:

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

But the API sends a response as attachment with content type `text/json; charset=UTF-8`. And Spring raises the error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.String] and content type [text/json;charset=UTF-8]
```

The response I get is in the following form:

```
{
  "some.key.a": "some translation for a",
  "some.key.b": "some translation for b",
  "some.key.c": "some translation for c"
...
}
```

I expected to assign the response to a String variable and parse it later.
Any idea on what is going wrong here ? Thank you.

Comment: Addin dexplictely converters like that: `private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverters() {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        return converters;
    }` then `restTemplate.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());` didn't solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

according to the [JSON-specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) the content type of JSON should always be "application/json".

One possible fix would be to edit the request and set the correct content type.

Fortunately I am from the [PhraseApp](https://phraseapp.com) Team and could simply fix this on our side ;)

You should be able to use it with your original code now!

If you need further help, send me a PN or an email at vincent@phraseapp.com

Comment: Vincent, thank you for your response. I've already got a feedback from PhraseApp saying that was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the following steps to get it works:

1. Use `/api/v2/projects/{projectId}/locales/{localeId}/download`
2. Create a custom converter as follows:

   public class PhraseTextJsonConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
       public PhraseTextJsonConverter() {
           setSupportedMediaTypes(initMediaTypes());
       }

   ```
   private List<MediaType> initMediaTypes() {
       return Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "json", DEFAULT_CHARSET));
   }
   ```

   }
3. Add converters to the template:

   ```
   protected static RestTemplate createRestTemplateWithConverter() {
           final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
           final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
           httpMessageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
           httpMessageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
           restTemplate.setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverters);

           return restTemplate;
       }
   ```

   and later a custom one:

   ```
   private void addPhraseTextJsonConverter() {
           restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new PhraseTextJsonConverter());
       }
   ```

To be able to get all the translations as a Map, I had to use `ParameterizedTypeReference`as follows:

```
protected ResponseEntity<HashMap<String, String>> requestPhraseApp(final HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity, final URI uri) {
        ParameterizedTypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {};
...
return restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, typeRef);
...
}
```

4. Do not forget to init the request parameters to get all the translations in a Map:

   List urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
   urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file_format", "simple_json"));

That's it.